# How to give google receive permission in kivy buildozer?

Tags: android, kivy

How can I set this permission = com google android c2dm permission receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `buildozer.spec` file, you probably just need to uncomment the `permissions` section and add in the relevant permissions you require. This is the section I'm referring to in `buildozer.spec`:

```
# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET
```